# Replace certain numbers/words in MonoDevelop. Typed wrong

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I made an enormous script, but now I realize I typed one number wrong in every section (I have over 120 sections). Is there a way to easily replace the number to another number in every line? Or will I need to do this manually?

Comment: Does your editor not have a find & replace function?

Comment: @tzhx I have been googling for a replace function, but I can't find it. Could you explain where I could find this? EDIT: Also when I type numbers in the search function it doesn't show up with anything.

Comment: @TZHX I am terribly sorry for wasting your time. I found it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace function is in the search panel, then click "Replace in files": http://prntscr.com/apnbn1 .